# Flask api request, read csv and save as json

Tags: python, json, csv, flask

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
json_url = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "data", "results.json")
json_data = json.loads(open(json_url).read()).
```

What I want to hopefully do is, that it reads my csv file, column - question, and loads it as json format.

[image: this is how my csv looks like]

Comment: where you are using term ???

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas for this issue i think.

```
import pandas as pd
read_csv = pd.read_csv('path/csv_name.csv',delimiter= ',') # or delimiter = ';'
read_csv.head() # display your data and check it
csv_to_json = read_csv.to_json(orient = 'columns')
```